# how to solve Value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10, tried to convert it to list map function with float but still didn't work, CNN model

Tags: python-3.x

```
        s = [str(i) for i in result]
        a = int("".join(s))
        result = "Predicted Traffic Sign is: " +classes[a]
```

It's showing an error here-

```
  a = int("".join(s))
Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.\n 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]'
```

Comment: Could you put your result iterable used in `s = [str(i) for i in result]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
[str(i) for i in result if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].